# Jqgrid imgFormatter

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid and have added a graph column to it, But the graph is not appearing and I don't know how to get the row number in Jqgrid. I want the graph in each row according to the data of the row I have fetched the data from server Side but don't know how to use that with Jqgrid. Will you'll please help me out to sort  out my problem ?
Thanks...

Comment: Could you explain how you provide graphs from the server? Do you have an url which provides graphs as images? Do you can use `<img>` with the url to display the graph?

Comment: Yes I have used this url 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:" + parameters+ "&chs=50x60"'it is not accepting values more than 1000. I m passing this url in <img> tag

Comment: Please help me out. What to do next Is there any other way to create graph in column of html table through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter). In the colModel add `formatter: myFormatter`
Then define the function

```
function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
    { return "The Value You Want to Display In The Cell"; }
```

The value returned by the formatter function will be displayed in the cell

- cellvalue - is the value to be formatted
- options - is an object containing the following element
  options : { rowId: rid, colModel: cm} where rowId - is the id of the row colModel is the object of the properties for this column getted from colModel array of jqGrid
- rowObject - is a row data represented in the format determined from datatype option. If we have datatype: xml/xmlstring - the rowObject is xml node,provided according to the rules from xmlReader If we have datatype: json/jsonstring - the rowObject is array, provided according to the rules from jsonReader